# Loading a .png into eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm trying to read the pixel values of an image for a project. However, when I try to read the image in Eclipse, I get a `Null`.

This is the instruction I'm using:

```
BufferedImage image =ImageIO.read(MyClass.class.getResource("/Resources/bird_small.png"));
```

Resources is a source folder with the path: `/Project/Resources`.

The program is saved in the path: `/Project/src/MyClass.java`

The program works fine when I run it directly with Terminal (with some minor alterations). 
I have seen some similar posts on this, however none of them seem to help me.

Comment: Just create new File with relative path from root of project to actual picture file, you don't need resources.

Comment: getResource() uses the runtime classpath, which is based on the project's Java Build Path, thus /Project/Resources isn't /Resources relative to anything in the classpath.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Resources` should be in the `src`

```
ProjectRoot
         src
            Resources
                 bird_small.png
            MyClass.java
```

When you build your project, Eclipse will copy the everything in the `src` into the class path.